# array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Tags: php

Есть переменная, объявляющая многомерный массив:

```
$some_array = array(
    array('filters') => array()
);
```

Я хочу обратиться к элементу `filters`, чтобы вставить в него какие-то данные:

```
array_push($some_array['filters'], $some_another_array);
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

PHP что, требует, чтобы массив ни в коем случае не был пуст? Что за бред?

Comment: в `$some_array1` нет элемента `'filters'`, там есть элемент `0`, в котором уже есть элемент `'filters'`

Comment: @etki и так со всеми массивами? Обязательно нужно обращаться к массиву, указывая 0 индекс?

Comment: При попытке создания указанного у вас массива, должна была вывестись ошибка `Fatal error: Illegal offset type in...`.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin я перефразирую: это не ошибка array_push, это ошибка исключительно вашего кода, который передает в array_push null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не правильно инициализирован начальный массив -  в качестве индекса массив это как? Наверное вам надо так:

```
$some_array = array(
    'filters' => array()
);
$some_another_array = [];
array_push($some_array['filters'], $some_another_array);
```

Comment: А как нужно инициализировать пустой массив, чтобы после `json_encode` в жсоне не случалось такого: `{"proposals":["",{`

Comment: какого?  Пустая строка в качестве первого элемента? Два варианта, но суть одинаковая : инициализация пустым массивом
$ar1 = []; или $ar1 = array();