# PHP, как в array добавить null?

Tags: php

Как можно добавить в array null-значение? Array_push ругается:

```
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\wamp64\www\Retrofit\includes\DbOperation.php on line
```

Код

```
$array_sensor_light = array();
while($stmt->fetch()){ 
...
    array_push($array_sensor_light, $sensor_light);
...
}
$parameters = array();
....
$array_sensor_light = array_unique($array_sensor_light); 
...
parameters['sensor_light'] = array_sensor_light;
...
return parameters;
```

Comment: `array_push($array, null)`

Comment: array_push($array_sensor_light, $sensor_light); выдает эту ошибку

Comment: Покажите сам код с массивом и переменной. Ошибка же в `$array_sensor_light`, скорее всего.

Comment: Код добавил, переменная приходит из бд

Comment: Она может быть Null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите более детально на ваше предупреждение (не ошибка, а предупреждение):

> Warning: `array_push()` expects parameter 1 to be array, `null` given in
>   C:\wamp64\www\Retrofit\includes\DbOperation.php on line...

Переведем на русский язык текст предупреждения:

> Предупреждение: `array_push()` ожидает, что параметр 1 будет массивом,
>   null указан в C:\wamp64\www\Retrofit\includes\DbOperation.php в
>   строке...

Откроем документацию по методу [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php): добавляет один или несколько элементов в конец массива. Обрабатывает массив как стек и помещает переданные переменные в конец массива. Длина массива увеличивается на количество переданных переменных. Входные параметры

1. Входной массив
2. Значения, которые нужно добавить в конец массива

Исходя из сообщения, указанного в предупреждении можно прийти к выводу, что первый параметр, массив, в который вы хотите добавить значения - имеет значение null.

Также, в качестве совета, не рекомендуется использовать метод `array_push()`, если вы не используете результат выполнения операции добавления. Связано это с тем, что метод работает медленнее, чем стандартная конструкция добавления в конец массива. Для примера, чтобы добавить в конец массива значение, достаточно написать следующий код:

```
$array_sensor_light[] = $sensor_light;
```

Такое добавление в конец массива работает гораздо быстрее, чем `array_push()`. Прочитав документацию чуть более детально, можно найти следующее:

> Note: `array_push()` will raise a warning if the first argument is not an array. This differs from the `$var[]` behaviour where a new array is
>   created.

Что в свою очередь говорит нам о том, что `array_push()` вызовет предупреждение, если первый аргумент не является массивом. Это отличается от поведения `$var[]`, когда создается новый массив. То есть массив не был инициализирован при вызове `array_push()` метода.

Другими словами, значение `null` вы можете поместить в массив, просто нужно знать некоторые тонкости при использовании метода `array_push()`.

Полезные ссылки для ознакомления и изучения:

- [Документация PHP: метод `array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)
- [PHP `array_push` adding `null` instead of `integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18006156/5275890)
- [`array_push()` expects parameter 1 to be array, `null` given in](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709822/189339)